# Adding viaIR: true option Brownie

Tags: solidity, brownie, compiler

I'm getting
`` CompilerError: Stack too deep. Try compiling with `--via-ir` (cli) or the equivalent `viaIR: true` (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables. `` this error. According to solidity docs I need to add `"viaIR": true` option but I can't add the same option to the `brownie-config.yaml` file. Here is the file: `compiler: viaIR: true solc: version: 0.8.17 optimizer: enabled: true runs: 200`

Comment: If after using the viaIR it still fail then it is likely the contract is still too complex.

Comment: But in the remix, it was compiled successfully.

Comment: The PR for this feature is still open: https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/pull/1572

Answer (score 0):

Add viaIR to your brownie configuration (**only on master branch of brownie at the time of writing**)

```
$> cat brownie-config.yaml
[...]
compiler:
  solc:
    # viaIR option has been added in 0.8.13, you can adjust the version your need
    version: 0.8.13
    viaIR: True
```

See for more information https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/1477